# Easy XML serialization with custom conversion of node values?

Tags: c#

How can i deserialize and cast the following xml file?
I want Valid element be casted to bool property and Time object be casted in DateTime property

```
<Foo>
    <Valid>True</Valid>
    <Time>19/02/2012 00:25:50</Time>
</Foo>
```

And not with reflection please

Comment: @JohnKoerner - Ha! beat you by 23 seconds. It's sad that the only value this question brings is the race to who asks the obvious question first.

Comment: I know i can use XmlSerialize, but it cast them to string, i want it to cast to the real objects. can it be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xml deserialization.

Create your class with attributes:

```
class Foo
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public bool valid;

  [XmlAttribute]
  public DateTime time;
}
```

Remember - fields must be public.

And then:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
Foo foo = (Foo)xs.Deserialize(reader);
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

.net has a xmlserializer object that lets you serialize and deserialize an object into and from a xml stream but it creates its tags in a different way than your xml file.
Maybe you can create a custom serializer that will act according to you rules.

[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2006/05/19/78989.aspx) you can find an example.(it uses a xsd file to set the rules of serialization)

Comment: can you elaborate regarding the xmlserializer you mentioned? i might change the XML if needed. Thanks

Comment: if the schema of your xml file is not important you can create a type as Maciej Dopieralski mentioned and xmlserializer will do the rest for you :)